# A question on the domain of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Let $\log$ be the main branch. What is the domain of the complex function $f(z)=\log(1/(1-z^{2}))$?

Comment: For which $z$ does $\frac{1}{1-z^2}$ _not_ lie in the domain of the chosen branch of $\log$?

Answer (score 2):

If the main branch is the complex plane minus the non-positive reals semiaxis, then you need to check when

$$\text{Re}\,\left(\frac1{1-z^2}\right)\le0\;,\;\;\text{Im}\,\left(\frac1{1-z^2}\right)=0\;$$

For exaple, putting $\;z=x+iy\implies z^2=x^2-y^2+2xyi\;$ , so

$$\frac1{1-z^2}=\frac1{1-(x^2-y^2)+2xyi}=\frac{1+y^2-x^2-2xyi}{|1-z^2|^2}$$

so we get that

$$\text{Im}\,\left(\frac1{1-z^2}\right)=0\iff2xy=0\;\;\ldots$$

And don't forget that we **also** need $\,z^2\neq 1\,$ ...